# is there any Alternative for sleep() function for increasing performance in python?

Tags: python, arrays

There is one program continuously  running which will check any file coming to particular directory or not if new file come it will put into database for that i used sleep() function but it will degrade performance (consider this program run on server side) so i need other alternative??

Answer (score 0):

If you're on linux [pyinotify](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify) is a good library for this.